# Is it possible to mark the cookie ASP.NET_sessionID as secure

Tags: cookies, https, asp.net-mvc-4, session-state

After a security audit I got the requirement to set the cookie ASP.NET_sessionID  as "secure".

Right now the flag is not set.

Can I use SessionIDManager to set it as secure? I am already using it to change the value of the Session cookie after logging in with this code:

```
            System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager manager = new System.Web.SessionState.SessionIDManager();
            string oldId = manager.GetSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            string newId = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
            bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;
            manager.SaveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newId, out isRedir, out isAdd);
```

**EDIT**

I saw that I can set

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="true" />
```

But I only want to have this one cookie secure

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954821/preventing-csrf-with-the-same-site-cookie-attribute/ (has answer about ASP session too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should enable you to set the cookie as secure:

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sessionCookieKey = Response.Cookies.AllKeys.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ToLower() == "asp.net_sessionid");
    var sessionCookie = Response.Cookies.Get(sessionCookieKey);
    if(sessionCookie != null)
    {
        sessionCookie.Secure = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `Application_EndRequest`? My `Global.asax` has only `Session_End` and `Application_End`.

Comment: Just add it to your Global.asax file and you should be good to go

Comment: I updated the sample, you need to retrieve the cookie and not just the key to the cookie

Comment: I think session cookie should be done in Session_Start as @Alagappapillai suggested.

Answer (score 5):

**Simply write the code for pass security audit.**

```
void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
            }

    }
```