# force secure cookie on IIS 6 without code source access

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a closed source app (asp.net) running on IIS 6/Windows Server 2003.
I need to force the use of the flag "secure" on session cookie.
How I can do that without access to the application source code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running the whole application under HTTPS.

If you have access to the Global.asax file without it needing to be re-compilied (unlikely) you can add code into it to mark cookies as secure.

[Is it possible to mark the cookie ASP.NET_sessionID as secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182054/is-it-possible-to-mark-the-cookie-asp-net-sessionid-as-secure)