# SessionID Change after Post to Bank URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recently I got a problem with my page
it was working fine last week
I don't change anything at all  but suddenly after submit form and post to another website (Bank Payment) and returning to my site sessionId Changed and all session data lost.

i check all solution in the web:
1. set data in Session Object 
2. set data in Session_Start() Global.asax
3. use Response.Redirect(url,false flag)

P.S.: I use java script to submit form

Comment: [ASP.NET webform loses session when getting posted data from another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671278/asp-net-webform-loses-session-when-getting-posted-data-from-another-domain)