# Aviso Same-Site/Aviso Same-Site

Tags: wordpress, same-origin-policy, samesite

My site is showing some warnings on my site about the Same Site attribute, I found in another question (question link below) a solution but it uses Web.config and I can't find it in my Cpanel
I use Wordpress hosted on Cpanel
Could you give me a hand over? I can't find a solution
Thanks in advance

[Image Error Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQBeb.jpg)

[Same-Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954821/preventing-csrf-with-the-same-site-cookie-attribute/60215613?noredirect=1#comment106508973_60215613)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These warnings are all related to `google.com` sites, not your site. You are only responsible for cookies from your domain. Try testing the functionality you are concerned about in an incognito window. If anything is broken, then check the console for warnings specifically linked to your domain.

You can find more context on this on https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained.

Comment: But how can I get these notices off the website? Or just hide them?

Comment: We'll look at reducing the false positives for these in the future. I know it generates a fair amount of console noise, but we needed to ensure we raised awareness here. One thing you can do is use `-cookie` in the filter field for the console view, though be aware that will filter out all messages mentioning the word "cookie".